# integration test - unit test seperation and best practices with visual studio 2010 + tfs

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, integration-testing

In our big application written with C# we have automated tests. 
Some of tests are integration tests; they are mostly testing integration points with other systems, they are slower than unit tests and to get them to succeed on a new machine some configuration is needed.
Some are unit tests; they are much faster, do not need any configuration.
In related test projects we have two folders in general: UnitTest and IntegrationTest. Hence I have not an option to run them seperately.
What I need is, clear seperation between unit and integration tests. I want to be able to run only integration tests or just unit tests.

How can I achive this seperation? What are your experiences on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visual studio go to the Test menu > Windows > Test List editor.  All test methods can be selected/deselected in this window.  At the top left click the arrow and choose Run checked tests or debug checked tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the TestCategory attribute (just Category in NUnit). Then run the tests in that category.

something like TestCategory("Unit") or TestCategory("Integration")

Comment: How can you run tests from a particular category from Visual Studio?